# How can I change date format ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new and I would like to know if I can change this format:

response_format_day-picker-react:
[image: response_format_day-picker-react]

To `format_BigCalendar`:
[image: format_BigCalendar]

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)